# Compactness of a set implication

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, compactness

Let $Y = \{0, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3},...\}$

I now that $Y$ is compact subset of the real line.

Let $a \notin Y$

But from here how can I show that there exists a $\delta$ $\gt$ $0$ such that

$|a-M| \geq \delta$ for all $M$ $\in$ $Y$

Comment: How can this possibly be true? Take $a_n = -{1 \over n}$. Then $|a_n -0| = {1 \over n}$.

Comment: $\delta$ depending on $a$ is possible but you are asking for one $\delta$  that works for all $a \notin Y$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy "...but you are asking..." OP's query has ambiguity here.  Your interpretation reasonable but not forced.  Alt interpretation is : Let $a$ be some **fixed** element not in $Y$.  Then choose $\delta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know that $Y$ is compact. Therefore, because $a\in Y^c$, you know that $a$ is an element of an open set.

Now, an open set in $\mathbb R$ is **defined** as:

> A set $S\subseteq \mathbb R$ is **open** if and only if, for every $s\in S$, there exists some $\delta>0$ such that $(x-\delta, x+\delta)\subseteq S$.

This definition provides *precisely* the delta you require.

Answer (score 1):

If $a < 0$ or $a > 1/2$ we can take $\delta = -a$ or $\delta = a - 1/2,$ respectively. Otherwise $a \in \left( \frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n+1} \right)$ and we can take $\delta$ to be the lesser of the distances from $a$ to either endpoint.